# How to play audio and video in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, media-player

I am porting an ASP. NET application to  MVC .in one page i need to play audio and video file .
For that i used MediaPlayers.dll in the application. 
In asp .net i usd it like shown below

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MediaPlayers" Namespace="MediaPlayers" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

and i accessed this dll using following code

```
     <cc1:MediaPlayer ID="MediaPlayer1" runat="server" Width="250" Height="42" autoStart="True"
                                                                                MovieWindowSize="0" ShowControls="True" UIMode="full" WindowLessVideo="True"
                                                                                AllowHideControls="True" AllowHideDisplay="True" Balance="0" ButtonsVisible="True"
                                                                                DisplayMode="0" EnableContextMenu="True" Enabled="True" Filename="" fullScreen="False"
                                                                                Invisible="False" Loop="1" Rate="1" ShowDisplay="False" StretchToFit="True" Volume="100">
                                                                            </cc1:MediaPlayer>
```

i can access it from code behind  using the id Mediaplayer1.

But now in mvc, how i can include this dll in my application and how can i access it from controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor Views offer their own handling of media players.  A [description](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/10-working-with-video/) is on the mvc site.